# Python Tkinter: Status bar not working if menu uses add_separator

Tags: python, menu, tkinter, statusbar

I have created a Menu with 2 options in my GUI, and I also used add_separator() in between the 2 options. There is also a status bar which provides descriptions when mouse is over any options.

My question is, how come any options after the separation line does not provide any description in status bar? Did it change its index location?

```
def helpMenuStatusBar(self, event = None):
   if self.parent.call(event.widget, "index", "active") == 0:
      self.statusBar.set("Select available files")
   elif self.parent.call(event.widget, "index", "active") == 1:
      self.statusBar.set("About This Application")
   else:
      self.statusBar.set("")

self.helpMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0, postcommand = self.updateMenu)
self.helpMenu.add_command(label = "Available files", command = self.availableFiles, state = "disabled")
self.helpMenu.add_separator()
self.helpMenu.add_command(label = "About", command = self.onAbout)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu = self.helpMenu)
self.helpMenu.bind("<<MenuSelect>>", self.helpMenuStatusBar)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the active item index to see if the index has changed?

Comment: Oops! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a separator line, this would count as one of the menu items. So in this case:

```
def helpMenuStatusBar(self, event = None):
   if self.parent.call(event.widget, "index", "active") == 0:
      self.statusBar.set("Select available files")
   elif self.parent.call(event.widget, "index", "active") == 2:
      self.statusBar.set("About This Application")
   else:
      self.statusBar.set("")
```